# My XML is failing validation using namespaces from accellera

Tags: python, xml, xsd, xml-validation, ip-xact

Here is the xml that I am trying to turn in to a markdown file using this python package: https://pypi.org/project/ipxact2systemverilog/.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Generated by PeakRDL IP-XACT (https://github.com/SystemRDL/PeakRDL-ipxact)-->
<ipxact:component xmlns:ipxact="http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014 http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014/index.xsd">
  <!--There are unimportant meat filler items in here but I have left them out for simplification-->
</ipxact:component>
```

When I run the command:
`python ./vcg-env/bin/ipxact2md --use-schemaloc -s $gitroot/output-files/ip_xact_test.xml -d $gitroot/output-files/registers_markdown.md`

Here is the error I get:

> ip_xact_test.xml:3:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_CVC_ELT_1: Element '{http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014}component': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.

Even when I strip out the few hundred lines in the middle of the xml to actually only have the one **ipxact:component** element I still get the same error.

I have tried to only have the one component element and strip all the 'meat' out just to confirm that the 'component' is my problem. It still gets the same error.

Comment: I am not familiar with the input vocabulary but it seems the tool you want to use has a different schema https://github.com/oddball/ipxact2systemverilog/blob/master/ipxact2systemverilog/xml/component.xsd with a completely different target namespace to the one your XML sample and your linked schema uses i.e. `http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1.5` vs `http://www.accellera.org/XMLSchema/IPXACT/1685-2014`. That is why I think you get the error message.

Comment: ipxact, spirit, IEEE 1685 are all the same std, but different names given over time.
The tool oddball at gitbub is the 1.5 version.  What's not the same version as your other tool is using.  Please feel free to send a merge request